# Clash of clans bluestacks to original?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I started playing Clash of Clans on my mobile with Town Hall level 2. Then I uninstalled it and I started playing a new Clash of Clans account on my laptop with BlueStacks. When I click on the 'Link a device' button it showed whether I wanted to load my previous account, but I want to link my new account to the phone again but not the original account.

Answer (score 1):

So let me get this straight...

You started playing Clash of Clans on your phone with the Google account email of, let's say: xxx@example.com
Then you started a new base on Bluestacks.
Now you want to link the new base on Bluestacks to the phone, and get rid of the original one on the phone?

Okay, so make sure that on Bluestacks, you are linked to a new Google account in settings (yyy@example.com), then on your phone, unlink your game with the original account (Google email, xxx@example.com) and click the button again to link a new Google account, add the account from Bluestacks (yyy@example.com) if not already there. If it asks for a confirmation, type "CONFIRM". Boom, now the devices should be synced and linked.